# Why did the latest ROR break <%= x.ems.name %>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have updated to the latest Ruby and Rails. Doing testing and one of my pages breaks. I am using MongoDB and ROR.

Here is where the page fails.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
2020-03-31T02:45:34.167626+00:00 app[web.1]:     28:     <% @drivers.each do |x| %>
2020-03-31T02:45:34.167627+00:00 app[web.1]:     29:     <tr>
2020-03-31T02:45:34.167627+00:00 app[web.1]:     30:       <td><%= x.email %></td>
2020-03-31T02:45:34.167628+00:00 app[web.1]:     31:       <td><%= x.ems.name %></td> <-- x.x.name
2020-03-31T02:45:34.167628+00:00 app[web.1]:     32:       <td><%= x.first_name %></td>
2020-03-31T02:45:34.167628+00:00 app[web.1]:     33:       <td><%= x.last_name %></td>
2020-03-31T02:45:34.167629+00:00 app[web.1]:     34:       <td><%= x.drivers_license %></td>
```

It appears that using x.x.y is not allowed in the new ROR? Or something changed so User model isn't pulling ems object.

Here is the underlying code:

EMS Controller

```
def approve_drivers
    ensure_root
    @drivers = User.drivers_for_stat_to_approve
end
```

USER.rb

```
def self.drivers_to_approve
    User.where(:type => DRIVER).ne(:stat_approved => true).desc(:created_at)
 end
```

Comment: If `x.ems` is nil, then you're going to get a NoMethodError exception. You can make sure every User you get has a "ems" with name, or use a safe operator when invoking name.

Comment: The code before grabbed both now in the in Ruby 2.4 and Rails 4.2 and MongoDB 3.6 it does NOT. I didn't change any code.  The code above is apparently grabbing Drivers but not sure how to grab EMS and put them all togehter or how to use a safe operator.

Comment: safe operator worked for now. Still need to figure out what broke underneath